# Collect responses and make stats in Google Forms with ECMAScript6

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ecmascript-6, google-forms, google-apps-script-editor

I'm collecting survey results in a Google Form using the Script Editor. My script looks like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var allResponses=[];
  for (var j = 0; j < formResponses.length; j++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[j];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
      allResponses.push( itemResponse.getResponse() );
    }
  }
  var jsonRes=JSON.stringify(allResponses);
  MailApp.sendEmail("noreply@mydomain.com", "Survey Results", jsonRes);
}
```

This works just fine. Now I would like to add some stats, like calculating the number of results for each response. For that I was like to use ECMA6 `Map` in a simple way like:

```
// flatten the array 
var words=allResponses.map(a => a.join(',')).join(',').split(',')
// map reduce and calculate occurrences of the map keys
var chart=[...words.reduce( (m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map() )].sort((a,b) => b[1]-a[1])
chart=chart.map(function(i) { return i.join(",")})
chart=chart.map(function(item,index) { return ((index+1)+","+item)})
var jsonRes=JSON.stringify(chart);
```

This will just output my responses list like

```
[
"1,responseA,1024",
"2,responseA,956",
"3,responseA,433"
]
```

etc.

Unexpectedly this will cause an error into the Google Script Editor, so I though it was the ECMA6 arrow operator, so I have moved back to function:

```
var words=allResponses.map(function(a) { return a.join(',') } ).join(',').split(',');
  var map=words.reduce(function(m,v) { return m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1)}, new Map() );
  // convert back Map entries to Array
  var chart = Array.from(map.entries());
  chart.sort(function(a,b){ return (b[1]-a[1])});
  var jsonRes=JSON.stringify(chart);
```

Funny story: The `Map` object is `undefined` ergo Google Script does not support `ECMAScript6` or I'm doing something wrong, do I?

**[UPDATE]**

This is the working Google Script solution thanks to the response below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var allResponses=[];
  for (var j = 0; j < formResponses.length; j++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[j];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
      allResponses.push( itemResponse.getResponse() );
    }
  }

  var words=allResponses.map(function(a) { return a.join(',') }).join(',').split(',');
  var chart = words.reduce(function(m,v) {m[v] = m[v] ? m[v] + 1 : 1; return m;}, {}); // Added
  chart = Object.keys(chart).map(function(k) {return [k, chart[k]]}).sort(function(a,b) {return b[1]-a[1]}); // Added
  chart=chart.map(function(i) { return i.join(",")})
  chart=chart.map(function(item,index) { return ((index+1)+","+item)})
  var jsonRes=JSON.stringify(chart);

  MailApp.sendEmail("noreply@mydomain.com", "Survey Results", jsonRes);
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing just the spread operator?

Comment: Yes in the second version I have moved to `Array.from(map.entries());` instead of `[...]`. And removed also the `=>` operators.

Comment: The [official Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) docs (updated May 2017) list which JavaScript versions are supported.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems to be stuck at `ECMAScript5`. So I need a different implementation of the chart calculation. :(

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks let me try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this sample? Google Apps Script cannot use ECMAScript6 yet. So `Map.prototype.set()` and `Map.prototype.get()` also cannot be used. I modified your script to be able to use at Google Apps Script. The modified script works at GAS.

#### From :

```
var chart=[...words.reduce( (m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map() )].sort((a,b) => b[1]-a[1])
chart=chart.map(function(i) { return i.join(",")})
chart=chart.map(function(item,index) { return ((index+1)+","+item)})
var jsonRes=JSON.stringify(chart);
```

#### To :

```
var chart = words.reduce(function(m,v) {m[v] = m[v] ? m[v] + 1 : 1; return m;}, {}); // Added
chart = Object.keys(chart).map(function(k) {return [k, chart[k]]}).sort(function(a,b) {return b[1]-a[1]}); // Added
chart=chart.map(function(i) { return i.join(",")})
chart=chart.map(function(item,index) { return ((index+1)+","+item)})
var jsonRes=JSON.stringify(chart);
```

[jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/nv4g35f5/3/)

I don't know whether this is the best modification. Since I didn't know the original data, if this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution! I have updated my code with the full script with your solution!

Comment: @loretoparisi Thank you for your reply. I'm glad for being useful for you. And I could study from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a map, and can't use a POJO, why not load a polyfill?

the best one is `core-js` which is the one Babel uses for all ES6+ features. You can even make a custom build of just the features you want